# querying using collections.variable as condition in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, and recently popped over from MySQL.
I have two collections, orders and customers. Both have CustomerID fields.
Trying to return documents from orders that match the CustomerID fields in customers, essentially orders.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID.

However, nothing happens.

This is the customer collection.
[image: Customer collection]

The order collection.
[image: Order collection]

And the query.
[image: query]

Any advice how to go about querying properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's alright.
I discovered $lookup. Geez ain't it useful.